# If a $\sigma$-algebra is countable, then it is generated by the collection of all atoms

Tags: measure-theory

Let $(\Omega, \mathcal F)$ be a measurable space. A set $F \in \mathcal{F}$ is an **atom** of $\mathcal{F}$ if for any $G \in \mathcal{F}$ such that $G \subset F$, it holds that either $G=\emptyset$ or $G=F$. I'm trying to prove a claim in page 5 of this [note](https://ipgold.epfl.ch/%7Eleveque/Lecture_Notes/APA_lecture_notes_1819.pdf), i.e.,

> **Theorem:** Let $\mathcal A$ be the collection of all atoms of $\mathcal F$. If $\mathcal F$ is countable then $\mathcal F$ is generated by $\mathcal A$, i.e., $\mathcal F = \sigma (\mathcal A)$.

However, I'm stuck at proving $F \cap A_0 \in \sigma (\mathcal A)$. Could you elaborate on how to proceed?

---

*My attempt:* We assume $\mathcal A = (A_n)_{n=1}^\infty$. Let $A_0 := (\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty A_n)^c \in \mathcal F$. Then for all $F \in \mathcal F$,
$$
F = \bigcup_{n=0}^\infty (F \cap A_n).
$$

For $n \ge 1$, we have $F \cap A_n \in \{A_n , \emptyset\}$.

Comment: First note that the collection of atoms is finite. This is because each union of atoms is unique. If there were infinitely many atoms there would be uncountably many unions of them. Next take a measurable set $A$ and let $B$ be the union of all atoms that are subsets of $A$. If $A\neq B$, then $Y_0=A\setminus B\neq \emptyset$.Since $A$ is not an atom, there is a proper measurable subset $Y_1\subset X_0$. Put $X_1=Y_0\setminus Y_1$. Repeat the argument with $Y_1$ and so on, defining the disjoint measurable $X_k$. Unions of $X_k$  would be all different and uncountably many.

Comment: Thank you so much @user85667!